# Binary tree function does not work with templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, binary-tree

Hello I will be happy if you could help me understand why the following error occurs and how do I can fix it, The error is part of a binary tree.

thanks !!

the error -

> error C2955 'BSNode': use of class template requires template argument list

the part of the code -

```
template <class T>
BSNode& BSNode::operator=(const BSNode& other)
{
_data = other._data;
_left = 0;
_right = 0;

//deep recursive copy
if (other._left)
{
    _left = new BSNode(*other._left);
}

if (other._right)
{
    _right = new BSNode(*other._right);
}

return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you need to provide the template parameter:

```
BSNode<T>& ... const BSNode<T>& other ...
```

The compiler might infer the parameters for the two constructor calls. If that's not the case, you need to provide the parameter for them, too.

Btw, templates are often implemented in their header files because it is often hard or impossible to split their declaration from their implementation.

Comment: But now after this correction I get the following error " Expected a class or namespace" what to do ?

Comment: @yronmosh Could you post more code? Maybe that will help someone understand why you are getting that error? Maybe you are not qualifying the template parameter with namespace?